# Случайное число из массива, не равное 0

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть некий массив целых чисел вроде `[5, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 2, 9]`
Требуется выбрать случайное число из этого массива, но не равное 0.
Использовать `random` с проверкой на 0 пока не будет подходящее число не рационально по времени и теоретически можно искать почти бесконечно. Другой вариант - проход по этому массиву и создание нового массива, отбрасывая все нули, после чего выбрать `random` из нового массива. Это тоже затратно и требует дополниельной памяти. Есть ли другие варианты подобного поиска?

Comment: Уточните насколько большой массив, сколько в нем нулей и сколько времени вы теряете по 1 и 2 варианту. А то овчинка выделки может и не стоит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если количество нулей в массиве велико, т.е. метод "проб и ошибок" применять нецелесообразно, то задачу запросто можно решить за один проход по массиву без дополнительной памяти, т.е. не создавая никакого нового массива и не модифицируя существующий.

Просто проходим по нашему массиву от начала до конца, игнорируем нулевые элементы, подсчитываем ненулевые, и каждый раз, когда встречается ненулевой элемент, "берем" его с вероятностью `1 / K`, где `K` - это количество встреченных на текущий момент ненулевых элементов`. Когда весь массив просмотрен, последний "взятый" элемент - это и есть наш равновероятно выбранный.

Это классическая "[резервуарная выборка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)" для случая одного резервуара. Только в вашем случае нужно игнорировать нулевые значения.

Например, на С это может выглядеть так

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  const unsigned a[] = { 5, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 2, 9 };
  unsigned n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;

  unsigned take, nz = 0;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    if (a[i] > 0 && rand() % ++nz == 0)
      take = a[i];

  printf("%u\n", take);
}
```

---

Разумеется, если вам нужно проводить такую выборку много раз на одних и тех же входных данных, то имеет смысл все таки просто сначала один раз "отфильтровать" исходный массив, исключив из него нули.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сжать массив на месте

```
zcount = 0
for i in range(len(A)):
     if A[i] == 0:
         zcount +=1
     else:
         A[i - zcount] = A[i]
```

При необходимости zcount последних элементов занулить

Answer (score 0):

Если в лоб, находим элемент, пока 0 переходим к следующему.

```
import random

lst = [5, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 2, 9]
idx = random.randrange(0, len(lst))
while not lst[idx]:
    idx += 1
    if idx > len(lst):
        idx = 0
print(idx, lst[idx])
```

Если декларативно

```
from itertools import chain

lst = [5, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 2, 9]
idx = random.randrange(0, len(lst))
print(next(filter(bool, chain(lst[idx:], lst))))
```

Comment: Автору вопроса, очевидно, нужна равновероятная выборка среди ненулевых элементов. У вас же никакой равновероятности нет: чем больше нулей стоит в массиве перед значением, тем чаще оно будет выбираться. В частности, на приведенном примере в правильной реализации значение 2 должно выбираться в 40% случаев. Ваш же вариант будет выбирать 2 в 62.5% случаев. 62% вместо 40% - это очень грубый перекос.

Comment: @AnT Знаю. Но просили просто еще один вариант, и в определенных условиях, он имеет смысл. При единичном числе выборок, ошибка неравномерности не накопится. Если же выборок больше, смысл в таких алгоритмах пропадает, в пользу прореживания исходного массива. На вскидку, это произойдет при количестве выборок >= len(arr)/count(zero), что для заявленного массива, всего 3 выборки.